# How to configure magento admin on a different server

Tags: magento-1.9

I would like to configure magento frontend on one server and backend in a different server. Googled for stuff which can help me in creating this but unable to find the steps.

Can someone please help me with the steps for configuring the magento backend on a different server so that i can separate frontend and backend in two different servers.

I am not a developer and i configure mostly with the help of tutorials. So, any detailed explanation on how to do this is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.